# Kivy App Stuck on Presplash

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

After some trouble with buildozer (which in hindsight I probably could have worked around now), I built my Kivy .apk with Python-for-Android successfully. Thanks to all those who've tried to solve these problems before, I've worked around a lot of other problems and come a version of my .apk that doesn't get past the presplash. According to `adb logcat`, the app runs through everything except starting the main loop:

```
I/python  (10880): Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
I/python  (10880): AND: Ran string
I/python  (10880): Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
I/python  (10880): main.py
I/python  (10880): [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/data/org.kivy.dropprApp/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_18-07-12_3.txt
I/python  (10880): [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
I/python  (10880): [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.5.0 (default, Dec 24 2015, 05:56:40) 
I/python  (10880): [GCC 5.3 20151204]
I/python  (10880): [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
I/python  (10880): [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
I/python  (10880): [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
I/python  (10880): [INFO   ] [Audio       ] Providers: audio_sdl2 (audio_ffpyplayer ignored)
I/python  (10880): [INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
I/python  (10880): [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
I/python  (10880): [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
I/python  (10880): [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <gl>
I/python  (10880): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 2.0 14.01003'>
I/python  (10880): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'NVIDIA Corporation'>
I/python  (10880): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'NVIDIA Tegra 3'>
I/python  (10880): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
I/python  (10880): [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <2048>
I/python  (10880): [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
I/python  (10880): [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
I/python  (10880): [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
I/python  (10880): [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
```

And it just ends there, still on the presplash, indefinitely.

I used this:

```
p4a apk --private /home/collin0599/Documents/Droppr/Droppr-0.20 --package=org.kivy.dropprApp --name "Droppr" --version 0.20 --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy==1.9.0,openssl,python3crystax --android-api 19 --orientation portrait --icon /home/collin0599/Documents/Droppr/Droppr-0.20/droppr_icon.png --presplash /home/collin0599/Documents/Droppr/Droppr-0.20/presplash.png --ndk-dir /home/collin0599/Documents/Droppr/crystax-ndk-10.3.2 --arch=armeabi-v7a
```

to create the .apk with Python-for-Android with my 32-bit Ubuntu 16.04 computer, and I'm running the .apk on a (older) Nexus 7 running Android 5.1.1 Lollipop.

Here also are the final lines of my code. (the whole thing is ridiculously long, and I suspect the error has something to do with this part)

```
KV_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'main'))
resource_add_path(KV_PATH)


class FallingBlocksApp(App):
    """Main App"""
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file("main.kv")
        sm = Manager()
        sm.file_load()
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: sm.msBegin(), 2)
        # sm.menuScreen.begin()
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    FallingBlocksApp().run()
```

`msBegin()` is just a function within my ScreenManager that calls a function within one of my screens. I've had trouble with it before because the .kv file wasn't loading in time, which is why it's scheduled by the Clock

Any help would be appreciated. I've done an hour or so of research on just this issue and nothing's come up. I'm really stumped. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I also technically wrote the app in python 3.6, but I'm fairly certain nothing in my code wouldn't work on 3.5. Also, I found that I get this error saying `Unsatisfied linker when loading ctypes`

```
E/art     (30055): dlopen("/data/data/org.kivy.dropprApp/files/app/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/org.kivy.dropprApp/files/app/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so" not found
V/pythonutil(30055): Unsatisfied linker when loading ctypes
V/pythonutil(30055): Loaded everything!
V/PythonActivity(30055): Setting env vars for start.c and Python to use
V/PythonActivity(30055): Access to our meta-data...
I/PythonActivity(30055): Surface will NOT be transparent
```

**EDIT 2:** I just reebuilt it with buildozer, and I'm getting the same errors, on top of this new one:

```
 globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
I/python  (18954):   File "/data/data/org.kivy.droppr.dropprapp/files/app/crystax_python/stdlib.zip/hashlib.py", line 113, in __get_builtin_constructor
I/python  (18954):     raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
I/python  (18954): ValueError: unsupported hash type blake2s
I/python  (18954): ERROR:root:code for hash sha3_224 was not found.
I/python  (18954): Traceback (most recent call last):
I/python  (18954):   File "/data/data/org.kivy.droppr.dropprapp/files/app/crystax_python/stdlib.zip/hashlib.py", line 243, in <module>
```

Same problem, not getting past the presplash and starting the main application loop. Here's my `buildozer.spec`

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Droppr

# (str) Package name
package.name = dropprapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.kivy.droppr

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = /home/collin0599/Documents/Droppr/Droppr-0.20/

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,kv,gif,ttf,png,jpg,wav,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.292

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy==1.10.0,python3crystax==3.6

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
presplash.filename = /home/collin0599/Documents/Droppr/Droppr-0.20/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
icon.filename = /home/collin0599/Documents/Droppr/Droppr-0.20/droppr_icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3.6

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.10.0

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 1

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Android API to use
android.api = 19

# (int) Minimum API required
#android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
# android.ndk = 10.3.2

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
android.ndk_path = /home/collin0599/Documents/Droppr/crystax-ndk-10.3.2/

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
# android.sdk_path = /home/collin0599/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-linux/

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to stable
p4a.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
p4a.bootstrap = sdl2


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```